# c++ two tbb::parallel_for loops efficiency

Tags: c++, tbb

In my code I call parallel_for twice:

```
parallel_for( do some stuff ); // I want this operation to finish first
parallel_for( do some other stuff ); // then I want to do this
```

1) Does this approach create physical threads twice ? and makes it slower ?

2) If needed, what would be the best method to replace those two calls of parallel_for ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) No, TBB has single shared pool of threads which are created lazily on demand. So lazily that completion of the first `parallel_for` does not guarantee creation of all the threads.

2) Not needed.