# Is there a break command for tbb::parallel_for

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, tbb

How can you `break` out of a `tbb::paralel_for`, similar to a sequential `for`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c++ two tbb::parallel\_for loops efficiency](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38618074/c-two-tbbparallel-for-loops-efficiency)

Comment: What does that question have to do with breaks??

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can throw a dedicated exception. TBB runtime should capture exception in thread running particular task causing a tasks group to be cancelled and exception to be rethrown from the root of cancellation group.

Comment: +1 That looks like the way to do it: [Intel® TBB - Exceptions and Cancellation](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/506073)

Answer (score 2):

You can throw an exception, or you can use the cancellation API. In the latter case, the "replacement" for `break;` is `tbb::task::self().cancel_group_execution(); return;`. However, neither gives you the guarantees of the `break` in a serial loop. More exactly, any loop iterations that follow (in the serial sense) the cancellation/exception might still be executed by other threads; moreover, some of iterations preceding (in the serial sense) the cancellation/exception might never run.

If the body of `tbb::parallel_for` has a loop inside (e.g. the one that iterates over a `blocked_range`), you might consider breaking out of that loop in case `tbb::task::self().is_cancelled()` is `true`; this might reduce wasted work and finish the loop faster.

For additional details you can check the TBB documentation, e.g. https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Exceptions_and_Cancellation.html and https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/task_scheduler/cancellation.html.

If in the serial code you use `break` to find the "leftmost" point (e.g. the minimal loop index, or the first item in a container) that satisfies a condition, you should not use cancellation or exceptions, as the result could be incorrect. Instead, use a form of reduction (e.g. `tbb::parallel_reduce`) to select the "leftmost" one of all suitable points. A possible optimization is to use an atomic variable (specified outside of the loop) to keep the minimal suitable index, and skip all iterations with a bigger index. For updating the atomic variable, you would need to use `compare_and_swap` operation to check if another thread might have updated it with a smaller value than the one found by the current thread.